# Django - query the records in all tables that have the foreign key equal to the selected record in the main table

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django I want to query the records in all tables that have the foreign key project = ProjectMain's chosen pk. So if I choose a record in ProjectMain and it's pk=2 I also want the records from the other three tables where the foreign key product=2.

Tables Methods, Things, and MoreStuff can have multiple records with project=2.

Here are the tables:

```
class ProjectMain(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filler = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Methods(models.Model):
    method_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    method_test = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Things(models.Model):
    thing1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    thing2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class MoreStuff(models.Model):
    stuff1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stuff2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've been trying Django querysets and am getting nowhere. Please help.

Comment: are you tried serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them via the `related_name` property as defined in [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

```
project_main = ProjectMain.objects.get(id=2)
methods = project_main.methods_set.all() # All the Methods related to the instance
things = project_main.things_set.all() # All the Methods related to the instance
more_stuffs = project_main.morestuff_set.all() # All the Methods related to the instance
```